# split string with awk and delimiter

Tags: log, awk

i have log file like :

```
1::
10::
127.0.0.1
172.17.1.1
```

i want awk to split string to columns on :: delimiter.
some thing like :

```
awk {print$1}
```

and the result :

```
1
```

and

```
awk {print$2}
```

and the result :

```
10
```

and

```
awk {print$3}
```

and the result :

```
127.0.0.1
172.17.1.1
```

i don't know how split with awk with delimiter ::.

Comment: Can you add the example of exact output expected?

Comment: What you are asking for cannot be done as awk doesn't work in the way you appear to think it does. You need to read the documentation for awk and understand what it does better.

Comment: @Iain, nope, see the souravc's answer

Comment: @Danatela: Given the input file the $2 and $3 requirements cannot be met in the way that the OP appears to think awk works. Yes, you can jump through hoops for the small example given but that doesn't scale to larger log files.

Comment: `awk` works on each line at a time, and does not do splits accross lines. The OP must understand this. `sed` doesn't do this either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set field-separator using `-F` option. Use the following commands in terminal,

```
$ awk -F "::" 'NR==1 {print $1}' logfile.txt 
1
$ awk -F "::" 'NR==2 {print $1}' logfile.txt 
10
$ awk -F "::" 'NR!=1 && NR!=2 {print $1}' logfile.txt
127.0.0.1
172.17.1.1
```

[`NR`](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-18) variable stores the line number. For example consider your file, with `::` as 
field-separator

```
        $1          $2        $3
NR=1    1
NR=2    10
NR=3    127.0.0.1
NR=4    172.17.1.1

and so on.
```

If you use `.` as field-separator it will be like,

```
        $1          $2        $3     $4
NR=1    1::
NR=2    10::
NR=3    127         0          0      1
NR=4    172         17         1      1
```