# access to field's element via awk

Tags: programming, awk

I have the following columns:

```
_111_   [555]
_222_   [666]
_333_   [777]
_444_   [888]
```

I want to access the **111** from `_111_`. or **888** from `[888]`.

How to access the fields elements with `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
  awk '{gsub("_|\\[|\\]","",$0); print $1 "-" $2;}' prova.txt
```

**awk** read each line and use " " (white space) as field separator, **gsub** remove chars: '_' '[' ']', so $1 and $2 will contains token without undesiderable char.

This script will output:

```
  111-555 
  222-666 
  333-777 
  444-888
```

If you would access exactly `_111_` and `[8888]` as first token and last token, try this:

```
  awk '{gsub("_|\\[|\\]","",$0);if (NR == 1) print $1;}END{print $2}' prova.txt
```

In this case the output will be:

```
 111
 888
```

Here is [awk manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/9base-awk.1.html) where you can found more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you have those data in a file `file.txt`

Access 111 as,

```
cat file.txt | tr -d "[]_" | awk 'NR==1 {print $1}'
```

Access 888 as,

```
cat file.txt | tr -d "[]_" | awk 'NR==4 {print $2}'
```

about [accessing the fields elements with awk](https://askubuntu.com/a/437263/127327).